# how to properly fix MVVM scaffolding issue with duplicate name tag? (ASP Core 2.2)

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, mvvm

Here's my problem, I have a `Book` that contains `List<Page>` that contains `List<Line>` and I'm trying to create a view that will edit my book. This view contains all the lines from the book. I've made an MVVM for `List<Page>` that calls smaller MVVM for `List<Line>`. The problem is that MVVM is not counting all `Line` as one single form, so this happens:

```
<form>
<h1>Page one</h1>
<input type="hidden" name="[0].lineContent" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="[1].lineContent" value=""/>
<h1>Page one</h1>
<input type="hidden" name="[0].lineContent" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="[1].lineContent" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="[2].lineContent" value=""/>
</form>
```

Each time my for loop for page iterates, my for loops in lines get reset to 0, this creates duplicate name entries.

There are multiple ways to correct this, the easiest:

- Build input by hand with unique name id instead of using HTML helpers

My question is the following: **how can I achieve a clean razor that can be reused, and that will not duplicate name entries in my form?**

## UPDATE:

#### Context:

Just like the book exemple up, my models have the same structure.

in my case I have a Submission that contains a list of Section that contains a list of SubSection that contains a list of SubmissionLine.

Here's my main view:

```
        @model 
   QuotingPlus.Models.Submission

  @{
       ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
   }

<form id="submission-form" asp-action="Edit">
     <div>
         <p class="d-inline-block">
             <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" 
    href="#multiCollapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1">Edit submission details</a>
        </p>
        <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="d-inline-block">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                    <a href="/Clients/Details/@(Model.IdProjectNavigation.IdClientNavigation.IdClient)">@Model.IdProjectNavigation.IdClientNavigation.FirstName 
@Model.IdProjectNavigation.IdClientNavigation.LastName</a>
                </li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                    <a href="/Projects/Details/@(Model.IdProjectNavigation.IdProject)">@Model.IdProjectNavigation.Name</a>
                </li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">@Model.Number</li>
            </ol>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col mb-3">
            <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
                <div class="card card-body">
                    <h1>Submission details</h1>
                     <hr/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="IdSubmission"/>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="IdTypeSubmission" class="control-label"></label>
                                <select asp-for="IdTypeSubmission" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.IdTypeSubmission"></select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="IdTypeSubmission" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="IdProject" class="control-label"></label>
                                <select asp-for="IdProject" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.IdProject"></select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="IdProject" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Number" class="control-label"></label>
                                <input asp-for="Number" class="form-control"/>
                                <span asp-validation-for="Number" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="save-warning" style="display: none;" class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <strong>WARNING!</strong> Make sure you save before leaving.
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" onclick="SetWarningDisplayPreferenceCookie();">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div id="carouselIndicators" style="height: 100% !important;" class="carousel slide pb-5 mb-5" data-interval="false">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            @{
            Html.RenderPartial("SubmissionSectionEditor",  Model.SubmissionSection.ToList());
            }
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-secondary mb-0 pt-2 fixed-bottom">
            <div>
                <button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default text-white">
                    <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 2em;">
                        save
                    </i>
                </button>
            </div>

            <a class="col text-center mh-100 pt-2 pb-2" href="#carouselIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="false"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="col text-center mh-100 pt-2" href="#carouselIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                 <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="false"></span>
            </a>

            <div>
                <a asp-action="Index" class="btn text-white">
                    <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 2em;">
                        cancel
                    </i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here's SubmissionSectionEditor.cshtml

```
@model List<SubmissionSection>

@{
    var isFirstCarouselItem = true;
}

@for (var indexSection = 0; indexSection < Model.Count(); indexSection++)
{
    <div class="carousel-item @((isFirstCarouselItem) ? "active" : "")">
        @{
            isFirstCarouselItem = false;
        }

    <h1>@Model[indexSection].IdSectionNavigation.Name</h1>
        <div id="@(Model[indexSection].IdSection + "accordion")">


            @{
                var submissionSubSections = M odel[indexSection].SubmissionSubSection;
            }

            @if (submissionSubSections != null)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("SubmissionSubSectionEditor", submissionSubSections.ToList());
            }

        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Here's SubmissionSubSectionEditor.cshtml

```
@model List<SubmissionSubSection>

@for (var indexSubSection = 0; indexSubSection <  Model.Count; indexSubSection++)
{
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="@(Model[indexSubSection].IdSubSection + "SubSectionHeader")">
            <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="@("#" + Model[indexSubSection].IdSubSection + "SubSectionCollapse")" aria- 
   expanded="true" aria-controls="@(Model[indexSubSection].IdSubSection + "SubSectionCollapse")">

    @Model[indexSubSection].IdSubSectionNavigation.Name
                </button>
             </h2>
         </div>
         <div id="@(Model[indexSubSection].IdSubSection + "SubSectionCollapse")" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="@(Model[indexSubSection].IdSubSection + 
"SubSectionHeader")" data-parent="@("#" + Model[indexSubSection].IdSubmissionSectionNavigation.IdSection + "accordion")">
            <div class="card-body">
                <table class="table w-100">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Article</th>
                         <th>Total Material</th>
                        <th>Unit Price Material</th>
                        <th>Total Sub Contractor</th>
                        <th>Unit Price Sub Contractor</th>
                        <th>Total Workforce</th>
                        <th>Unit Price Workforce</th>
                        <th>Display</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @{
                        Html.RenderPartial("SubmissionLineEditor", Model[indexSubSection].SubmissionLine.ToList());
                    }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Here's SubmissionLineEditor.cshtml

```
@model List<SubmissionLine>

@for (var indexLine = 0; indexLine < Model.Count; indexLine++)
{
    <tr>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[indexLine].IdSubmissionLine)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[indexLine].IdArticle)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[indexLine].IdSubmissionSubSection)
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model[indexLine].Quantity, new {@type = "number", @step = "0.5", @min="0"})</td> 
<td>@Model[indexLine].IdArticleNavigation.Designation</td>
        <td>@Model[indexLine].TotalMaterial</td>

<td>@Model[indexLine].IdArticleNavigation.UnitPriceMaterial</td>
        <td>@Model[indexLine].TotalSubContractor</td>

<td>@Model[indexLine].IdArticleNavigation.UnitPriceSubContractor</td>
        <td>@Model[indexLine].TotalWorkforce</td>

<td>@Model[indexLine].IdArticleNavigation.UnitPriceWorkforce</td>
        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model[indexLine].IsDisplayed, new {@class = "checkbox"}). 
</td>
    </tr>
}
```

I only want to know **how I can keep this structure with MVVM and avoid the input name duplicate issue**?

## RE-UPDATE:

I'm not quite sure why this would be useful since I get name duplicate input, but here's my save action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, SuperAdmin, Employe")]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, Submission submission, [FromForm] List<SubmissionLine> lines)
    {
        var test = Request.Form;

        if (id != submission.IdSubmission)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            SubmissionUpdateHelper.SaveSubmissionModifications(_context, submission, lines);

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        ViewData["IdProject"] = new SelectList(_context.Project, "IdProject", "Name", submission.IdProject);
        ViewData["IdTypeSubmission"] = new SelectList(_context.TypeSubmission, "IdTypeSubmission",
            "TypeSubmission1", submission.IdTypeSubmission);
        return View(submission);
    }
```

Comment: Could you share your source code with helper tags generated this html?

Comment: What do you mean by `how can I achieve a clean razor that can be reused, and that will not duplicate name entries in my form?` Do you want to create generic custom Tag Helper that will allow you to put IList<T> as a value and will display each element on page? Do you want us to create clean solution with partial views? If so could you please provide more specific information about how your view models look like?

Comment: I've added informations, please review your down vote on my question

Comment: I've one question. Are you sure you are using MVVM pattern with Razor pages? ViewBag is not supported in Razor Pages which is MVVM patern, seems to me like you are using asp.net core mvc. Is that true?

Comment: @MathieuAuclair what does your controller model look like on `POST`ing? (`save`)

Comment: I am using AspNetCore and I use ViewData instead of ViewBag. Does MVVM input naming depend on ViewBag? Is there documentation on that? @LukaszBalazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've just added the input by hand so I could keep my MVVM pattern. I've also used an increment variable in TempData so I could keep track of the input

in Edit.cshtml

```
@{
    TempData["submissionLineCount"] = 0;
}
```

here's the new version of SubmissionLineEditor.cshtml

```
@model List<SubmissionLine>

@for (var indexLine = 0; indexLine < Model.Count; indexLine++)
{
    <tr>
        <input name="[@(TempData["submissionLineCount"])].IdSubmissionLine" value="@(Model[indexLine].IdSubmissionLine)" type="hidden"/>
        <input name="[@(TempData["submissionLineCount"])].IdArticle" value="@(Model[indexLine].IdArticle)" type="hidden"/>
        <input name="[@(TempData["submissionLineCount"])].IdSubmissionSubSection" value="@(Model[indexLine].IdSubmissionSubSection)" type="hidden"/>
        <td>@TempData["submissionLineCount"]</td>
        <td>
            <input name="[@(TempData["submissionLineCount"])].Quantity" value="@(Model[indexLine].Quantity)" type="number" step="0.5" min="0"/>
        </td>
        <td>@Model[indexLine].IdArticleNavigation.Designation</td>
        <td>@Model[indexLine].TotalMaterial</td>
        <td>@Model[indexLine].IdArticleNavigation.UnitPriceMaterial</td>
        <td>@Model[indexLine].TotalSubContractor</td>
        <td>@Model[indexLine].IdArticleNavigation.UnitPriceSubContractor</td>
        <td>@Model[indexLine].TotalWorkforce</td>
        <td>@Model[indexLine].IdArticleNavigation.UnitPriceWorkforce</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="[@(TempData["submissionLineCount"])].IsDisplayed" class="checkbox" value="@(Model[indexLine].IsDisplayed)"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {
        TempData["submissionLineCount"] = (Convert.ToInt32(TempData["submissionLineCount"]) + 1);
    }
}
```

This is clearly not the best way, I hope there will be more documentation on how to apply MVVM in AspNet.Core in the future...

If this answer gets deprecated, make sure to post your own!

Answer (score 0):

For showing sub-list properties in View, Try code below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BookName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="BookName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="BookName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Pages.Count; i++)
                {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Pages[i].PageName" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Pages[i].PageName" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Pages[i].PageName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @for (int j = 0; j < Model.Pages[i].Lines.Count; j++)
                        {
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Pages[i].Lines[j].LineContent" class="control-label"></label>
                                <input asp-for="Pages[i].Lines[j].LineContent" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="Pages[i].Lines[j].LineContent" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>

                }
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I already done that, this is not my question, how do you do it using MVVM? This is not clean

Comment: @MathieuAuclair What do you mean by `using MVVM`? For this way, it would not cause `duplicate name entries`. What you have done and got `duplicate name entries`?

Comment: check this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/mvvm-in-wpf/), this is MVVM (model view view model), and I know that your solution works, but I already done this before you posted this, it's not clean, I want to use MVVM